# WinForms Tab Control Causing Cross-Thread Operation

Tags: c#, winforms, cross-thread

This is the error I am receiving. I have a button on a winforms control (as depicted below). I have an async void method that is attached to the click event handler (as depicted below)
[image: Error]
[image: Button on second tab]

The issue that I am having is that this code runs **perfectly fine** when I first load in this form, I can click the button 1,000+ times and there is no cross threading errors that occur.

The **ONLY** time that I get this error is when I do the following

1. hide the form `form.Hide()` (with keeping a reference to the form)
2. show the form for a second time `form.ShowDialog()`
3. click the refresh button

It seems like **all** of the buttons on the form will then have some sort of cross-threading issue when calling into UI controls from async method calls. It is almost as if hiding and then re-showing the dialog does *something* to make new controls on a new thread **BUT** it never calls the Initialize method again.

Does anyone know why I am having an issue?

**EDIT**
This is also a VSTO excel addin project. The form is getting created by a ribbon button click and I hold on to a reference of the form in the ribbon class to re-show it

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve] with all of the steps to replicate this issue?

Comment: How's that [mcve] coming along?

Comment: I began working on it but couldn't replicate the exact issue I was having. I'll try to work on it some more tomorrow but it is late here. It may be a day or so before I'm able to put that together

Comment: I would suggest. 1. Check what thread the event is raised on (should be UI/Main thread). 2. What thread is used after the await (it should be the same). 3. That there is only one UI thread. I would expect that multiple UI threads could give the problem you are describing.

Comment: Try to understand which thread you are using when you create the form at the beginning and when you show the form later.

Use `Console.WriteLine(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);`


They should be the same.


Moreover do you have this problem only on `async` methods with `await`?

Comment: @GibbOne - This is why a [mcve] would be awesome.

Comment: @Enigmativity sure!

Comment: Check the SynchronizatinContext.Current in your Form.OnShown method. I've already seen that it get's lost under VSTO and is not a WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext anymore, thus not doing proper continuation on the main thread by using async/await. It is probably not a good idea to keep a reference to a hidden form in VSTO, why do you need that?